# Abstracting out a WHERE clause in a UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in MySQL that resembles the following:

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN (Select Country from Countries Where ID > 5) limit 1
UNION
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country IN (Select Country from Countries Where ID > 5) limit 1
ORDER BY City;
```

Is there a way to abstract out the

```
WHERE Country IN (Select Country from Countries Where ID > 5)
```

to have something like:

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN t1 limit 1
UNION
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country IN t1 limit 1
ORDER BY City
WHERE t1 = Select Country from Countries Where ID > 5;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Limit without order by is a bit pointless

Comment: the real query has an order by, i just chose a simple example

Comment: If you had posted a complete example up front instead of a "simple one", you may have already had a complete answer.

Comment: hi @user2779581, can you please stipulate the requirement in clear context... say you want to 1 top random customer which is not associated to 1 top random supplier

Comment: @Donnie  the actual query is much too long and a pain to read, the example in the question is verbose enough

Comment: @maSTAShuFu in the context of this question i want the first customer, and first supplier, given a list of countries that they can each come from

Comment: What does 'first' mean? Tables are not ordered.

Comment: jesus christ, why does it matter? I just want the first one, it's irrelevant

Comment: No, you cannot abstract the query in the `in` operator away in an efficient manner. Queries in the union are independent from each other

Comment: @Shadow thanks, post that as the answer and i'll mark the question as answered

Comment: There is no 'first', so if you don't explain what you mean by using it without an order, you are not making sense. PS Re your question see my answer.

Comment: The first is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot abstract the query in the `in` operator away in an efficient manner. Queries in the union are independent from each other, therefore any abstraction means you have to create a dataset accessible from both queries.

In the production version of mysql you have only 2 options:

1. Create a temporary table and select from that
2. As the deleted answer suggested: combine the two select query results first as a derived table, then filter it.

Neither is really efficient.

In the alpha version of v8.0 you csn use CTEs, which are slightly more efficient. But the reality is that in the union mysql executes the queries separately and such a criteria can easily be optimised by mysql.

Comment: An how does this add anything new to my answer?

Comment: v8.0 may not even be alpha, just a developlement milestone. The current production version is v5.7, which does not support CTEs. And there is not much point in suggesting a solution that is less effective, than the current one.